# Having trouble building a calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a simple calculator to learn javascript/jquery but seem to be getting quite confused on how to make it work. Basically at the moment I dont seem to be able to update my tally correctly, instead of the numbers/values being added together in a sum they are being concatenated instead, if anyone could give me some guidance on how I can get back on the right path with this and any other advice on how to make the code more efficient then that would be great. I don't want anyone to give me the correct script just yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/edRk9/4/

Thanks all in advance for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `val()` method returns a string, and the `+` operator will concatenate if one of the operands is a string. You can convert the value to a number using `parseInt`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)</sup>*:

```
$('input.num', '#buttons').on('click', function() {
    // when click a number it appears in #result        
    currentNumber = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $('#result').html(currentNumber);
});
```

Note, for parsing decimal numbers, use `parseFloat`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)</sup>*, not `parseInt`.

Comment: Also for parsing you could use +'10', but the parseInt('12', 10) is more secure way and more readable.

Comment: I think parseInt will not work as necessarily with decimal numbers. But maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @Alex Dn - You're right. For decimals, use `parseFloat`. I added a note to that affect in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

parseInt, parseFloat or multiply value by 1 before sum or use eval(), but it's the worst case :)